# pivot: row in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

-1
down vote
I have a query returning following

```
Id        Type     data         char
1111      date     1999-06-30   NULL
1111      name     NULL         James
1111      string1  NULL         Yes
1111      string2  NULL         No
2222      date     1965-07-09   NULL
2222      name     NULL         Chris
2222      string1  NULL         No
2222      string2  NULL         Yes
```

I would have

```
Id       date          name   string1 string2
1111     1999-06-30    James  Yes     No
2222     1965-07-09    Chris  No      Yes
```

Is it possible ti obtain that result using PIVOT sql function?

Comment: What code have you tried and what was the result?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need to go dynamic, a simple conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
Select ID
      ,date    = max(case when [type]='date'    then [data] end)
      ,name    = max(case when [type]='name'    then [char] end)
      ,string1 = max(case when [type]='string1' then [char] end)
      ,string2 = max(case when [type]='string2' then [char] end)
 From (
        -- Your Query or Table
      ) A
 Group By ID
```

Comment: @Ann Happy it helped.